# Trying to delete files older than x days vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file, windows-services, find, delete-file

I have a basic bit of code which I am using to delete text files within a given directory:

```
For Each file As IO.FileInfo In New IO.DirectoryInfo(filePath).GetFiles("*.txt")
    If (Now - file.CreationTime).Days > intdays Then file.Delete()
    Next
```

`filePath` is the directory where the files reside.

`intdays` is a variable which determines how many days the files should be retained for.

To test the code i set intdays to 0, assuming that it would delete any files in the directoy. However it doesn't, but creates no errors.

The time "Now" is #2/8/2012 13:59:00 PM# which is greater than 0. But I'm confused as to why it doesn't then delete the file?

Comment: Shouldn´t it be that when you subtracting dates with the difference less than 1 day, the days property of TimeSpan zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the dates is **less than a day**.

You are calling the `Days` property, which is an integer type - this will be `0` for intervals that are less than a day long.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, i changed it to >= for testing purposes and it deleted the files. I shall wait a day with it set to > to see if it works then.

Comment: @ASmith: or you can just use the TotalDays property, which is a decimal, so a 12-hour timespan would be 0.5 TotalDays.

Comment: @A Smith: Why wait? Set your local time back a few days and create the files, or if you lack sufficient rights on your local machine to do that, just (temporarily) modify your `If` to read `Now.AddDays(3)`.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to use `LastWriteTime` instead of `CreateTime`, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it

```
        Dim d = New Date(2012, 11, 21, 16, 0, 0)
        Dim dGreater = New Date(2012, 11, 21, 17, 0, 0)
        Dim result = dGreater - d
        Console.WriteLine(result.Days)
```

So when you are subtracting the dates that has difference less than one day the `Days` property of the result is 0, i.e. truncated to the lesser integer value.